# Column does not allow DBNull.Value - Synapse

Tags: sql, pipeline, azure-synapse

I am running a pipeline that calls a stored procedure and sinks the table to another dedicated pool. I made sure that in the source table I have no NULL VALUES in intercompany table (I have named a field in sink table as Intercompany too), so I'm not really sure why I am getting this error.

`Message=Column 'Intercompany' does not allow DBNull.Value.,Source=System.Data`

Comment: How are you performing this in Synapse? Pipeline Copy activity? Data flow? Some other method?

Comment: what is the datatype of the field 'Intercompany' can you share the ddl?

Comment: I have fixed my stored procedure by added `ISNULL` to `InterCompany` like this `CASE 
   WHEN ISNULL([Intercompany].[DisplayValue], '') = ''
    THEN 'No Intercompany'
   ELSE [Intercompany].[DisplayValue]
   END AS [Intercompany]`  . It worked fine. I made mistake when I looked up the intercompany filed there was no `NULL` values but after `LEFT JOIN` it could have some `NULL` values.

Comment: If issue resolved, please post it as answer to help other community members.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my stored procedure by changing `WHEN [Intercompany].[DisplayValue] = ''` to `WHEN ISNULL([Intercompany].[DisplayValue], '') = ''` which now allows me to store the `NULL` values too. I made a mistake when I looked up the `InterCompany` table there was no `NULL` value but I missed the part that I have some `JOIN`s which may create `NULL` values.